# How to use partial views from different models in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am trying to code a simple blog with using ASP.NET MVC 5 Framework. I have done CRUD operations of Posts. I mean I can add new articles and manage them. When I wanted to add comments to articles, I stuck. Comments will be added to Details pages of articles. So I should add Create comment page to Details page.

I used Code First model and I have two models. Articles and Comments. I decided to use partial views to enter comments. But result is an error:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Article but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Blog.Models.Comment'.** Comments can not be added. I created 2 **PartialViews**, one of them is **_CreateComments PartialView** and other one is **_Index PartialView**

**Details View:**

```
@model Blog.Models.Article

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

 <div>
<h4>Article</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Author)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleContent)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ArticleContent)
    </dd>

</dl>
 </div>
 <div class="jumbotron">
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Comments/_CreateComments.cshtml", new Blog.Models.Comment())
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Comments/_Index.cshtml", new List<Blog.Models.Comment> { new Blog.Models.Comment() })
   </div>
```

**_CreateComment PartialView**

```
  @model Blog.Models.Comment
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Create")) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Comment</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommentContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CommentContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**_Index PartialView**
     @model IEnumerable

```
 <table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CommentContent)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommentContent)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CommentId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CommentId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CommentId })
    </td>
</tr>
 }

 </table>
```

Comment: Please show the `HttpPost` action that saves the comment.  Additionally, your `BeginForm` does not specify an action - this could also be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I edited my post I added comment adding action. I copied     BeginForm    from Create page. I did not understand what is wrong about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a ViewModel for that purpose. In POST, it will get the needed information. And in GET you will send the needed information.

For example: in GET you will send the article and needed areas. But in POST you will get the comment and commenter's name and date etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous issues with your code.

1. `@using (Html.BeginForm())` means it will post back to the
   `Details()` method (assuming that's the action which generated the
   view), so it would need to be `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create"))`
2. The controls your generating will have `name` attributes such as
   `name="Item2.Date"` which have no relationship to your `Comment`
   class (`Comment` does not have a property named `Item` which is a
   complex object with a property named `Date`)
3. The default value of a `DateTime` property is `1.1.0001 00:00:00`
   meaning that you have not initialized the value (e.g. `Date =
   DateTime.Today;`) but its not clear why you would need the user to
   enter a date anyway - surely that would be set to today's date in
   the controller immediately before you save the comment.
4. You have not indicated what scripts
   `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` is generating, but assuming
   you using the `jQueryUI` datepicker, you will need at least
   `jquery-{version}.js` and `jquery-ui-{version}.js` (plus `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` for validation)
5. You have a table in your form which will not display anything other
   that the initial values of a new `Comment` (and exactly the same as
   is being displayed in the textboxes) so it seems a bit pointless

Note also your view does not display any existing comments for an article which seems unusual.

There a numerous ways so solve this including ajax so the user could stay on the same page and continue to add more comments, but based on what appears to be your current UI, then the model in `Details` view should be just `Article` and use a partial to render a form for a new `Comment`

Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    ....
    Articles article = db.Articles.Find(id);
    ....
    return View(article);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Comment model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Date = DateTime.Today; // set date before saving
        db.Comments.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ....
}
```

View

```
@model yourAssembly.Article

// Render properties of Article 
....

// Add form for creating a new comment
@Html.Partial("_Comment", new yourAssembly.Comment)

// Add required scripts including jquery ui
```

and the partial view (_Comment.cshtml)

```
@model yourAssembly.Comment
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create"))
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Content, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> .m.Content, new { @class = "form-control" } })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Content, new { @class = "text-danger" })
  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Side notes:

1. Do not use `Tupple` in your views, especially for a view that
   involves editing since it generates `name` attributes which have no
   relationship to your model. Always use view models.
2. You do not generate a control for the `CommentId` property so there
   is no point including it in you `[Bind]` attribute (and in fact
   means someone could post back a value and result in your code
   throwing an exception.
3. Using `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags are not appropriate in your
   view (they are for *A description list, with terms and
   descriptions*). Use `<div>` and `<span>` elements.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your very informative answer. I created partial Views instead but this did not work also. I deleted all tuple staff. I cleaned it all. Updates and details are in Edit 2 of my post. thanks again.

Comment: You still have not followed all he advice I gave you. And what on earth is the point of the `_Index.cshtml` partial where you only ever pass it a new list containing one default `Comment` object which wont even have any values? And you never put scripts in partials, only in the main page (or layout). And you never use an action link for a delete action - it needs to be a POST, not a GET. As far as _"but this did not work "_ - what did not work?

Comment: Thanks for yor answers. how can I do this with using Ajax? I want to add Comments to details page. Could you attach some tutorial or document?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My answer does not use ajax. I just suggested you should use ajax because it will give far better performance than this solution which means do a normal submit and redirect each time rather than staying on the same page.